# Get the mentioned output by SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I appeared for an interview lately. The interviewer asked me the problem.
I have 2 tables:

First table is `Location` like this:

```
ID | City
---+-----------
 1 | Mumbai
 2 | Delhi
 3 | Bangalore
```

Second table is `Item` like this:

```
Item | Location_id
-----+-------------
  A  | 1,2
  B  | 2,3
  C  | 1,2,3
```

Now we want the output as below

```
Item | Location
-----+-------------------------
  A  | Mumbai,Delhi
  B  | Delhi,Bangalore
  C  | Mumbai,Delhi,Bangalore
```

Please help me write the query.

Comment: This is not a code writing service, and certainly not a service that will help you deceive your potential employer.  If the interviewer is allowing you to utilize resources to answer your question (which in this case I find hard to accept) then proceed, but indicate as such.  If not, then be honest with your interviewer.

Comment: I suggest you to read SO guidelines about good asking: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I assume you failed the test, and this wasn't take home, and want to understand how it should have worked? If not then you should not be getting us to help you here, if you don't understand code in an interview you will fail if you get hired.

Answer (score 0):

You want to `STUFF` all matching results into one column:

```
SELECT i.item, 
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + l.city 
           FROM location l 
           WHERE CHARINDEX(cast(l.id AS VARCHAR(4)),i.location_id)>0
           FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
    AS Location
FROM item i;
```

`CHARINDEX` finds the first instance of a substring in a string, in this case it finds that you have the number 1 for Mumbai, 2 for Dehli etc in your string of location_id.

`STUFF` combines your results into a single result.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/134a9/4)

UPDATE -

As pointed out by Rajneesh, this only works because your IDs are single digit. String splitting is probably the best way to handle the possibility of such IDs. That can still be done within this one query, without the need for a temp table.

```
SELECT i.item, 
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + l.city 
           FROM location l 
           WHERE l.id IN (select value from STRING_SPLIT(i.location_id, ','))
           FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
    AS Location
FROM item i;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/134a9/2)

Comment: test your code with these values                                                                                   INSERT INTO Location(ID, City)
                      Values(1, 'Mumbai'),
                      (11,'Bangalore');                                                                                    insert into item (item, location_id)
values ('B','11')

Comment: @RajneeshVaishwar It will not work with double digit IDs true, but it DOES work for the provided single digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query . String split works on SQL server 2016 and later versions.

```
 Select * into #temp 
    from #location l 
    join (
    select item,value  from #item
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(location_id, ',')
        ) A on l.id=a.value


     select
        item, 
        stuff((
            select ',' + u.city
            from #temp u
            where u.item = A.item
            for xml path('')
        ),1,1,'') as List
    from #temp A
    group 

by item
Drop table #temp
```

Comment: Why bother with the temp table and splitting the string?

Comment: all problems can have multiple solutions . Its one of them might not be the best one :)

Comment: You also forgot to `DROP #temp` at the end

Comment: yeh.. Edited now .Thanks

Comment: Your code here doesn't seem to work, tried it in a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/134a9/7) no results

Comment: Its working on my SSMS. May be some type of syntax handling over there.